# Xamarin Forms Pill Button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do you declar the `Button` in Xamarin Forms to be a pill button regardless of the width/height of the button? Is there a way to do this without resorting to native custom renderers? I would like to do this 100% in XAML.

[image: Pill Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without custom renderers. But here's a nice article about it: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/supercharging-xamarin-forms-with-custom-renderers-part-2

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `BorderRadius` property on the `Button` to round the corners to look like a pill.

Comment: You can now. Sadly you couldn't back in 2015 tho :)